# Why Shri Krishna referred Arjuna as conqueror of wealth?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita

**Bg 7.7** — O conqueror of wealth, there is no truth superior to Me. Everything rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread.

My question: Why Arjuna here is referred as conqueror of wealth? Did he amassed huge wealth or did he overcome greed & lust for money? Or is this related to Kuber in some way?

Comment: During the Indraprastha days, PAndava-s amassed huge wealths. There is a whole chapter describing that. You may find it just when Duryodhana etc. visit their fantastical palace. In general, such addressing was common during those days. Many a times Duryodhana has been referred as "sinless" by his fellows!

Comment: @iammilind being referred by fellows is fine but if it's being used by lord Krishna then there has to be something specific in it.